# Image circle mask, Flash actionscript 3

Tags: flash, image, actionscript, mask, masking

I am wanting to achieve a particular image effect using Adobe Flash (Actionscript 3).

I would like an image (width 200px, height 600px) to appear on the timeline by being revealed by different sized circles (varying from 30px-5px).

I am thinking of using an image mask and creating seperate circles across the timeline, so that when the movie plays, each random sized circle, one after one, will reveal the image at the end. So this is probably going to be quite time consuming....

Does anyone know a better way that I could achieve the effect? Also, does anyone know of any flash image effects helpers in general, I'm looking for something similar like green socks except for image effects...

Any help is very much appreciated!!!

Cheers,
Jess

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a beginner friendly framework for flash effects, Branden Hall wrote a nice library called "Hype"
http://www.hypeframework.org/

It is great for effects, transitions, and generative art.

Maybe try out using a transparent "BitmapCanvas" as a mask.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy - add all of your circles to a container which is the mask for your image.

```
// load image / place on stage
var circlesContainer:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(circlesContainer);

your_image.mask = circlesContainer;
```

Or if you're doing everything on the timeline you can obviously just create a MovieClip and put it in a mask layer above your image layer.